# Delay javascript loading in each view

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

i have a .js file that looks like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Content boxes expand/collapse
$(".initial-expand").hide();
$("div.content-module-heading").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div.content-module-main").slideToggle();
    $(this).children(".expand-collapse-text").toggle();
});
});
```

i need to load this file in each of my views, is there an elegant way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same code for all your pages, I would insert it into a JS file, for instance startApp.js, and will include this script as an HTML tag before closing the BODY

yourView.HTML

```
...
<script src="startApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ruby on rails then you can add it in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb or you can add it in app/assets/javascripts/application.js